# UJS Code Organization and Initialization

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, architecture, unobtrusive-javascript

My two-part question is something that seems very basic, but which I have not seen any discussion of in introductions, guides, or overviews to either UJS or jQuery. I have read through countless other topics/questions to try and find examples I could just copy the style or feel of, but the toy examples that ask 'How do I do X in jQuery?' and the like, never really explain or demonstrate the manner in which their solutions fit into a larger application.

In this way, my question is structural or architectural.

**The 'tl;dr' versions** of the questions basically ask "How do people *actually* organize and initialize Unobtrusive JavaScript code in large applications?" Specifically:

1. "When writing JavaScript in an Unobtrusive style, how can the code be organized across files? Should it even be done?" (I understand there are advantages to only sending one file to the client, which is then cached and all subsequent loads are faster).
2. "If relevant JS is no longer explicitly loaded with a page, how does one make sure the right code is properly initialized/called/used on the proper page(s) and time isn't wasted on running selectors that are irrelevant to the current page?"

**Long Version:**

After months of hand-rolling my own brittle, good-enough-for-now JavaScript in our Rails application, I am finally converting to the way of UJS and jQuery. I've now read all of http://jqfundamentals.com, save for "Advanced Topics" section. I'm getting the hang of jQuery quite easily, and my pages are doing what I want them to, *in isolation*.

As for "Unobtrusive JavaScript", I'm less clear but the idea seems to be primarily separating JS entirely external files, and strapping JS functionality into the page after the fact by *somehow* determining what page you are on and attaching functions after the document is ready. Please correct me if this is inaccurate or incomplete.

But what I don't understand is how to organize my code and make sure that the right JavaScript is included and attached to the right pages. All of the methods I can imagine seem either exceedingly inefficient, clunky, or invalidate some of the tenets of UJS.

The current state of affairs is that I have a massive and unwieldy application.js file, into which is crammed all sorts of selectors that are waiting to place functionality onto page elements that don't exist on 90% of my pages. That is, Page 1 has items A, B and C, whereas Page 2 has items A, D and E. This is frequently causing things to break. I feel like I am left with two unpalatable options:

1. Since I want to have the server only send one, large .js file, have my entire JS code in application.js somehow wrapped in a switch statement that figures out (?) which page it is on and makes only document.ready calls for elements it knows should be on that page. The obvious ways I could accomplish this feel very ugly, such as placing a single global JS variable inside the page and checking for it, which breaks the entire zen of UJS that drew me in the first place.
2. Split up my JavaScript into different files and selectively load them. That is to say, "I am in view01.html.erb, therefore I need to include view01.js," which deals with only elements on view01.html.erb. This seems better at first, but gets clunky fast when it comes to partials, mixing-and-matching .js files, and trying to stay DRY.

I went down this road of UJS because it had this very clean, zen-like appeal, but applied to a larger project it seems to be more trouble than it's worth. Yet people much smarter than me insist otherwise, and I completely agree that in-line and script-tag-bound JavaScript is clunky and ugly, which leads me to believe I am doing something wrong.

**What I have done so far**
(aka Even Longer Version, probably not worth your time to read):

**Phase 1:** I'm working on a Rails application, and so I began by taking the route presented in a number of RailsCasts tutorials that demonstrate code in application.js which finds an item via a selector and attaching some functionality to it. Things worked great and I had 2 or 3 pages doing all the nifty jQuery, Web2.0-ish, AJAX-y stuff that is hot with the kids these days. Awesome!

**Phase 2:** Then I made one more page, and things started to break. I had all my code in application.js accessing things via $('selector'). This new page didn't have any of the same elements as the other pages, and so when my code from the other pages tries to get the element with id='special_area', the call to $('#special_area')[0] breaks because it is empty. Null-checking the result of every single selector felt wrong, so I eventually bumbled my way onto the solution of not using the DOM elements I know and love, but working with these fancy jQuery Objects that can be chained. Neat.

**Phase 3:** I realize that with these Chained jQuery Objects, as long as all my IDs are unique, or I place some sort of unique DIV on each page, any elements that don't exist on the page will return an empty set and (hopefully) not break. I don't know enough to say for certain yet that they will not break regardless of what I want to do with them because they are empty, thus I'm not going to assume that is the case. But somehow I can see it marginally working out by brute-forcing ALL the elements in my entire app and somehow intelligently ignoring elements that don't exist on the current page.

Furthermore, jQuery Fundamentals guide discusses, repeatedly, how expensive it is to keep running selectors. And if I just brute-force run ALL my selectors and let it not apply those that don't exist, I'm placing a HUGE static overhead on each and every page, since as the size of my app grows, so does the single .js file, and each page has to check more and more elements that don't actually appear on it!

**Phase 4:** I learned about how namespaces are done in JS, and while I plan on using them, I don't see it as solving this particular problem. If they can, please explain. Beyond this point, my ability to articulate my disappointment and confusion has broken down, and I'm wondering **How do people *actually* organize and initialize UJS code in the Real Life™?**

Comment: Instead of checking for existing elements on every page load and conditionally execute the suitable code for the current page (what might result in poor performance as you correclty stated), you could try it the other way round. i.e.: in every special layout/page include a small inline javascript (minimize number of requests) that calls just the right initializer inside your appliaction.js. That solution might not strictly follow the UJS paradigma, but it might be practical/benficial enough to justify its usage.

Comment: I realize that this does not answer all of your questions above, but this is a good starting point for a nice way to control which JS will run / attach / whatever for a given controller and action: http://viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr Answer**

1. Split your code into AMD modules an load them using an AMD loader like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).  And yes, it *should* be done.
2. In your partial view simply `require()` and execute the appropriate module

**Longer Answer**

Using an AMD loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) allows you spearate your code into individual modules.  You can also store shared code (e.g. jQuery) in a common module and then use it as a prerequisite for your view modules.

You can read up on [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/why.html), [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and [using it with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html), but this is how I'd approach it:

1. Have you main document [include](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) and [configure](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) your AMD loader.  You'll probably want to load the shared modules (jQuery, etc.) so that the browser can cache them between requests.
2. For each partial view, [implement a coresponding JS module](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#defdep).
3. In your partial view, add a script block to load the module and execute its initialization function

**View Module**

Your module will look something like this (we're using jQuery as an AMD module, too):

```
js/partials/view01.js

define(["jquery", function($) {
  "use strict";
  return {
    init: function() {
      // This is where you do your UJS work for this partial
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

**Partial View**

In your partial view, you'll load the module and call the init function:

```
view01.html.erb

<script>
require("partials/view01", function(view) {
  view.init();
});
</script>
<!-- More HTML for this partial view -->
```